# Comparison JS: Abstract Equality Comparison

Tags: javascript, comparison

I have this example:

```
console.log("0"== 0)
```

Comparing the following documentation

[Abstract Equality Comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)

and looking at point 6, which corresponds to my case, that is

> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison !ToNumber(x) == y.

I get that:

**ToNumber("0")** is **0**, so **!ToNumber("0")** is **1**, so I get **1 == 0**, meaning I should get **false**.

Why is true on the console? Comparing the documentation I should get false.

Comment: What is your code for `ToNumber()`? It is not a function that's built-in or from a standard library.

Comment: @MichaelM. https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-tonumber the OP isn't talking about a JS function

Comment: `!` doesn't mean the JS logical not operator in that context: https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands

Comment: so? How should I read the documentation? am i missing something?

Comment: @Sarah it's not documentation, it's the language spec

Comment: can someone kindly explain to me the why of that result to understand better?

Comment: `!ToNumber(x) == y` says, convert `x` to a number and compare it with `y`. Remember, this _is not written in JavaScript_

Comment: why is that put " ! " ? It confused me with the not

Comment: The spec is not written in JavaScript. _"`!` is used to indicate that the following invocation of an abstract or [syntax-directed operation](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-algorithm-conventions-syntax-directed-operations) will never return an [abrupt completion](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-completion-record-specification-type)"_ - the spec describes what it means